# conditional include for opencv2/photo/photo.hpp c++ depending on OpenCV version

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to create a conditional Include, depending on the OpenCV version. Actually I'm compiling in 2 different platforms the same source code. I'm developing in Ubuntu 14 and I want to run My application in a Raspberry PI. The problem I have is with the:

```
#include "opencv2/photo/photo.hpp"
```

In the raspberry I have OpenCV 2.4.1 and In Ubuntu the 2.4.8. Every time I compile I have to change the includes in several files which is annoying, That Why I would like to make a conditional Include, but no Idea how to this specific one.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314508/conditional-include-in-c) and a [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930360/c-conditional-include-file-runtime) but I think is not the same problem.
I also compile with CMAKE just in case I can create a variable or something to create the conditional include.

Comment: I see you have accepted my answer! thanks, it would be great if you could post on it (or edit it) to include what you have to put after the equals!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use preprocessor directives and the `CV_VERSION` command to switch, like so:

```
#ifdef CV_VERSION=(I dont know what you need to equal it to)
#include "opencv2/photo/photo.hpp"
#endif
```